# Memory access gives different results

Tags: linux, memory, gcc, stack

I have function f2() that loops over frame pointers - so, it reads memory. If I in a previous function f1() print a value keep in ebp pointer - the next func f2() reads it as well. But without the print in f1() the f2() reads incorrect value.

So, the difference only in print code in f1, which just reads memory. Is it somehow linked with caching?

The print code in f1:

```
LOG(5, "r_ebp=%p, prev=%p\n", r_ebp, *(void **) r_ebp);
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't understand the question... can you show the code?

Comment: Basically the problem just with memory read - the different results.